# Flutter Multiple Scoped Models

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter app I am working on, and I want to have multiple scoped models.  The example given at https://pub.dev/packages/scoped_model#-readme-tab- shows how to listen to the models, but it doesn't show how to instantiate them.  I found this example online, where one is made to be the child of the other,

```
() => Navigator.push(context, 
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScopedModel<ModelA>
          model: ScopedModel.of<AppModel>(context).a,
          child: ScopedModel<ModelB>(
             model: ScopedModel.of<AppModel>(context).b,
             child: PageAB())))))),
```

My question is, is this the proper way to instantiate and listen to scoped models?  Thanks!

Comment: That is the correct way, but you might want to check out the [provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package. It does the same thing in a more robust way and is more actively (not to mention recently) maintained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the package "provider" (https://pub.dev/packages/provider) with it's `MultiProvider` instead of package "scoped_model".

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tidder!